# Increment label by 20 each button click

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I Increment a label by 20 each time I click a button I've tried with this code:

```
private int sjokolade = 0; (outside of void)
sjokolade = +20;
this.metroTile1.TileCount = 1;
label1.Text = (+sjokolade).ToString();
```

Thanks!

Comment: `sjokolade += 20;` and not `sjokolade = +20;`. `= +20` is assign `+20` but `+= 20` is increment by 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `+=` and not `=+` since the first is a shorthand for `sjokolade= sjokolade+20` and the second is setting it equal to positive 20.